# What's *nix terminal command to find and remove found files?

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, malware

I have a malware on my server.
So I've figured out how to find all that malicious files

```
 grep -r --include*.php "Some String from files" .
```

That seems work fine!

but how to delete them?
I've tried using xargs

```
grep -r --include=*.php "FilesMan" . | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

But got

```
rm: cannot remove `./www/wp-content/plugins/zuglohjetok/vaoaddiy.php:$default_action = FilesMan;': No such file or directory
```

Can someone share some magic line of code?

And also I've tried to look up for all recent modified files on server by "find", but that got me tons of files. Is there any other fancy methods to find malware or infected files?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but systems that have been infected by malware usually cannot be trusted. Partial recovery might lead you to think your system is secure again, which may not be the case. I would recommend wiping everything and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Frédéric, you're right! I'm still need to do some research on that. But it looks like malware got in by a web shell script, through some plugin in old unupdated wordpress. but that should be still confirmed. The script its self was just creating directories with index.html files  with redirect to some spammy websites. That all harm I've found has been done so far

Comment: Sorry to say that, but the fact that you've not found more doesn't prove the absence of more. Related: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @Jonas, no doubt! I still need to do some deep research. But from what I have found out already, this is the work of this script "Web Shell by oRb". And as far as I can tell, this script got in through some wordpress plugins. Thanks for the link, will read it

Comment: @AlexReds from what _I_ was able to find, its the worst category of malware you can get, as it gives the attacker something similar to a shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find some/dir -iname '*.php' -exec grep -q "some string" {} \; -delete
```

Use `-print` instead of `-delete` to make sure the command works as expected first.

Comment: So it works flawlessly. Thanks Ignacio for the quick respond!